# update a posts of other custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, query-posts, post-meta

i create a new custom post type which i named "invoice" and then i create an  new custom post type named "car" which contained a field "Km traveled" i want to update the field of "km traveled" of post "car" from the post type of "invoice".
that's mean when i submit to insert/update the invoice the post of car must be updated.
how can i make that? and if there is possible with example if exists

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [save_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) action along with [wp_insert_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) function for this. Something like following may work.

```
function tnc_update_car_details( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    // If this is a revision, don't continue
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        return;

    $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

    // If this is not an invoice post type, don't continue
    if($post_type !== 'invoice')
        return;

    $car_id = '1';

    wp_insert_post(
        array(
            'ID' => $car_id,
            'meta_input' => array(
                'km_travelled' => '300',
            ),
        ),
    );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'tnc_update_car_details', 10, 3 );
```

I've not tested though. Please let me know the result after trying.

Comment: is it possible to use that with this condition at that submit : if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

Comment: noticed that there was a mistake somehow. Just corrected that. with this code you don't need if(isset()).  This will automatically work when you publish/update an invoice